# Use script task to delete records from table using variables for tablename and date

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow that reads records from an API.
It then inserts those records in a SQL Azure database in a  table.
The problem is that the source data does not have a primary key. The source data does have identical records that are all valid.  I do not want to insert double records. I do not want to do a full load every time I fill that table.  So, the idea is to get a the last day of data from the source, delete the last day of data in the destination table and then insert the data from the source.
Since the source is quite slow, if I delete the data before starting the dataflow, my clients will be with incomplete data for several minutes up until 20 minutes.
I want  the time between deleting and writing the data to be as short as possible.
That is why I am thinking about using a script task  **in the dataflow**, after reading from the source and before writing in the destination table.

The script task would be deleting records from the destination table based on two variables: 1 for the date to select records to be deleted and one to decide on what schema.table that will be.

This is all controlled by variables.
`user::delete_date` is a datetime
`user::schema_table` is the schema_name of the table to delete records from. The table name is always the same but the schema varies.
`meta_inserted_date` is a field in the destination table of type datetime2

So the instruction I would like the script task to execute is:

```
DELETE FROM user::schema_table WHERE meta_inserted_date >= user::delete_date
```

Since I want this to be done in the dataflow I cannot use a Execute SQL Task.
The only way I see to execute SQL in the dataflow is to use a Script task.
I can understand scripts, can adapt them but writing is another thing… Please help?

Comment: Every row that is in your source query is going to fire the same delete statement, which is what you want for the first row but it'll get bothersome for the 70th million row.

Comment: ooops……….………...

Comment: @billinkc You should mark this as an answer so other fools like me can find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for billinkc's comment. I will post it as answer to help others who have the same issue.

Every row that is in your source query is going to fire the same delete statement, which is what you want for the first row but it'll get bothersome for the 70th million row.

Hope it helps you.